# Using the Bayes Theorem?

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian

> A certain town has two taxi companies, the Green Taxi Co (cars coloured green) and the Blue
>   Taxi Co (cars coloured blue). 10% of taxis are the Green and 90% are the Blue. There was an
>   accident on a dark evening, and the witness claimed a Green cab was involved. On future testing, they discovered that under the conditions of that evening, there was an 80% chance of correct identification of the cab colour (regardless of colour) and 20% chance of erring in colour identification. (assume neither company is more accident prone than the other)
>
> a. Before actually hearing the testimony of this witness, what is the probability that the
>   witness will claim that it was a Blue Cab involved in the accident that night?
>
> b. If we now have the testimony of the witness, who declares that the cab was Green, what
>   is the probability that it actually was Green?

I used a probability tree to solve this question but apparently, it was actually related to Bayes theorem. How I did (a) was use the probability tree and got $P(Witness~claims~Blue) = (0.9)(0.8)+(0.1)(0.2)=0.74$.
For (b), $P(Actually~green) = (0.1)(0.8)+(0.1)(0.2)=0.10$.

However, the answer for (b) was $\frac{.08}{.26}$ and I was supposed to use the Bayes Theorem. Can someone please explain why the Bayes is to be used instead of a sum of probabilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the events:

- $T_b$: witness think it's blue
- $T_g$: witness think it's green
- $I_b$: is blue
- $I_g$: is green

So we have:

- $P(I_g) = 0.1$
- $P(I_b) = 0.9$
- $P(I_g|T_g) = P(I_b|T_b) = 0.8$
- $P(I_g|T_b) = P(I_b|T_g) = 0.2$

In (a), you wanted $P(T_b)$, so you used $P(T_b) = P(T_b|I_b)P(I_b) + P(T_b|I_g)P(I_g)$

In (b), you wanted $P(I_g|T_g)$, so you use $P(I_g|T_g) = P(I_g)P(T_g|I_g)/P(T_g)$, where $P(T_g) = 1-P(T_b)$ (the answer you got on (a))

Note the difference between the two problems, in the second you wanted a conditional probability, so that's why you used Bayes Theorem.

Comment: I can't really grasp the difference between conditional probability and Bayes Theorem. I looked it up many times but I can't seem to understand.

Comment: The conditional probabilities the wrong way round (see answer below)

Comment: @Ray I don't even recall answering this as it was more than a decade ago. Anyway, I've change edited the question to make it a community wiki, fell free to edit it and improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Because Bayes Theorem combines prior information with collected data to create a posterior probability.  think about what you know (the prior probability of the cab being green = 10%) combined with 'collected' information, (that the witness identified the car as being green).  Use Bayes Theorem:

$P(B|A) = \frac{P(A|B)P(B)}{P(A)}$

You started the problem with a certain belief that the cab would be green (10%, since 10% of all cabs are green).  You have new information.  how should that affect your belief that it's 10 % likely that the cab is green?

Comment: Keep in mind that what you're trying to find out isn't $P(Actually Green)$ but rather $P(Actually Green|Witness claims Green)$

Comment: But then can't I just use the conditional probability instead of Bayes? I am slightly confused about which one to use sometimes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  You needed to use Bayes because you were looking for a conditional probability in part (b).  Bayes gives you the conditional $P(Actually Green|Witness Claims Green)$.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this when preparing a class. The accepted answer above has the conditional probabilities the wrong way round. If it is blue we identify it correctly 80% of the time etc. So we should have:

\begin{equation}
P(T_g|I_g)=P(T_b|I_b)=0.8
\end{equation}

and
\begin{equation}
P(T_b|I_g)=P(T_g|I_b)=0.2
\end{equation}

For (b) then we have:
\begin{equation}
P(T_g) =P(T_g|I_b)P(I_b) = P(T_g|I_g)P(I_g) = (0.2)(0.9) + (0.8)(0.1) = 0.26
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
P(I_g|T_g)=\frac{P(T_g|I_g)P(I_g)}{P(T_g)} = \frac{(0.8)(0.1)}{0.26} = \frac{0.08}{0.26}
\end{equation}